# WeeklyUsers list updation with latest Updated Value

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Currently I am facing issue, We need to find weekly Users list. There is a one field in MongoDB
Profile Collection caled lastActive. We need to print last week user count, what happens is this
lastActive field is updating every users session, For example: User X lastActive value is '2020-07-
14T10:10:10:12.000' If users logged in today 2020-07-21T09:10:12.000, then what happens lastActive
field is updating with today's Date based on session details, can someone please let me know how can I
calculate the exact count value of weekly users list, based on latest Updated value. Hope u clear my
issue.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate lastweek = LocalDate.now().minusDays(7);
String start = today.toString();
String end = lastweek.toString();
long weekly_userlist = profile_collection.countDocuments(Filters.and(Filters.gte("lastActive",end),Filters.lte("lastActive",start)));
```

Comment: What do you consider as week? There are several definitions.

Comment: Can u please explain, how can we achieve this ? Thank you

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit , can you please let me know, how can we acheive this ?

Comment: Again what is weekly? Does the week start on Saturday, Sunday, Monday? Or always the previous 7 days?

Comment: Yes, I have written in previous 7 days. Is this the right approach? if we consider it saturday as start day, sunday last end day, how can we acheive latest updated values

Comment: It depends on your requirements. Still not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: I am writing API for weekly users list count, by considering lastActive field of User Profile collection, what happends lastActive field is frequently updating based on user session value, user logged in last week, also use the application in today also , then what happens lastActive field is going to change todays value, so how can we get exact count users, by considering old last active values of users, how do we calculate weekly users count based on sessions? hope u clear my issue